# join belongsTo in find method

Tags: cakephp, join, model, model-associations

`Score` belongs to `Player`:

```
class Score extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Answer';
    public $belongsTo = array('Player');
}
```

In `PlayersController`, I want to get player scores, with his details.

**Question #1**: How to include `belongsTo` model in `find` method result? (join it)

**Question #2**: How to get sum of all scores distance (`Score.distance`) which belongs to that player? (I mean `SUM(Score.distance)`, group by `Score.player_id`)

**Note for Q1**: Because each player has a lot scores, I don't like to join scores in each `find` method I use in that controller. I want to get them in just 1 action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cakephp automagic not actually join tables as you can see in sql_dump in your layout at bottom.

You will see below queries.

```
SELECT `Player`.`id`, `Player`.`name`, `Player`.`created` FROM `players` AS `Player` WHERE `Player`.`id` = 10 GROUP BY `Player`.`id`

SELECT `Score`.`id`, `Score`.`player_id`, `Score`.`scores` FROM `scores` AS `Score` WHERE `Score`.`player_id` = (10)
```

Quite clear that its not actually join table so you need to do it following way.

And following will help you because **i have already tested it.**

In Player Controller you need to unbind score model first and then custom code to join score table as below.

In player model create one virtual field as below.

```
<?php
class Player extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Player';
    var $displayField = 'name';

    var $virtualFields = array
    (
        'Distance' => 'SUM(Score.scores)'
    );

    var $hasMany = array
    (
        'Score' => array
        (
            'className' => 'Score',
            'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
}
?>
```

For testing i manually added `conditions` to find player number `10 scores`

```
<?php
class PlayersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Players';

    function index()
    {

        $this->Player->unbindModel(array
        (
            'hasMany' => array
            (
                'Score'
            )
        ));

        $this->Player->bindModel(array
        (
            'belongsTo' => array
            (
                'Score' => array
                (
                    'foreignKey' => false,
                    'conditions' => array
                    (
                        'Player.id = Score.player_id'
                    )
                )
            )
        ));

        $order = "Player.id";
                $direction = "asc";
                if(isset($this->passedArgs['sort']) && $this->passedArgs['sort']=="Distance")
                {
                        $order = $this->passedArgs['sort'];
                    $direction = $this->passedArgs['direction'];
                    unset($this->passedArgs['sort']);
                    unset($this->passedArgs['direction']);
                }

                $this->pagination = array();

                $this->pagination = array
                (
                    'conditions' => array
                    (
                     'Score.player_id' => 10
                    ),
                    'fields' => array
                    (
                        'Player.*',
                        'SUM(Score.scores) AS Distance'
                    ),
                    'group' => array
                    (
                        'Score.player_id'
                    ),
                    'limit' => 15,
                        'order'=>$order." ".$direction
               );

              $playersScore = $this->paginate('Player');
    }   
}
?>
```

And the resulting array would be looks like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Player] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [name] => Dexter Velasquez
            [created] => 2012-08-02 12:03:07
            [Distance] => 18
        )
    )
)
```

For testing i have used [**Generate Mysql Data**](http://www.generatedata.com/#generator).

for sorting link

```
<?php $direction = (isset($this->passedArgs['direction']) && isset($this->passedArgs['sort']) && $this->passedArgs['sort'] == "Distance" && $this->passedArgs['direction'] == "desc")?"asc":"desc";?>
```

and display above link as below.

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Distance','Distance',array('direction'=>$direction));?>
```

Comment: cakephp actually find related table and append data to array. so you need to manually force cakephp to unbind old relation and join with bindModel... because as far as table are not joined you can not use other table field in query....hope u understand what i mean.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. But how can I do it with pagination component? and sort by Distance. (or other columns)

Comment: you don't need to worry for pagination because every paginated page will execute this code so your data will be accurate enough

Comment: Paginated pages are sorted by a table column. But here we don't have an real column and use a virtual column. How to sort All players by their distance? (and paginate pages)

Comment: Thanks. But it returns just 1 player (while we set `limit => 15` and I have a lot of players in table scores and players) and that player, have a `Distance`, which is sum of all distances in scores table, not just the player scores distance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it returns same result. Is `bind`, `unbind` and `virtualFields` needed in pagination?

Comment: Yeah now check update u must have paginate and bind unbine code in same action as in answer..

Answer (score 0):

So, `Player` has many `Scores`...

```
class Player extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Player';
    public $hasMany = array('Score');
}
```

... which means your `find()` in `PlayersController` can be something like...

```
$players = $this->Player->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'contain' => array('Score'), // <-- If you're not using Containable Behavior, remove.
        'conditions' => array('Player.id' => $id), // <-- Change or remove as necessary.
        'fields' => array(
            'Player.id',
            'Player.name',
            'Sum(Score.distance) as sum_dist',
        ),
        'group' => array(
            'Player.id',
            'Player.name',
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'Player.name',
        ),
    )
);
```

Hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Score.distance' in 'field list'

Comment: @kikio You are using the Containable behavior right? Or did you remove the 'contain' paramter and set 'recursive' correctly instead?